# Nothing happening after calling window.requestFileSystem in PhoneGap on iOS 7

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ios7

---

Hi there.

I'm trying to record an audio in PhoneGap, using PhoneGap 3.3.0 for iOS 7.

The first thing I'm doing is handling the file saving by doing this:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, requestFileSystem_success, requestFileSystem_error);
```

But nothing get's called after that: neither the success nor the error functions are called.

I added this:

```
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
```

to the config file, as sugested here:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/dev/doc/index.md

but nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: First of all, did you include file-work feature to your config file? You can look what should be added in docs (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html).
Does executing of "window.requestFileSystem" line result in JS error? Also it may be useful to provide more code (especially function where FS is requested and success and error functions).

Comment: Already solved it. A couple of things were missing.

Comment: @JeanPaul I'm having the same problem. Could you please tell me how you fixed it?

Comment: @Sourav, are you trying to record an audio in PhoneGap or are you having issues with this preference value?

Comment: @JeanPaul i was having problem in window.requestFileSystem but now its solved. Thanks

Comment: How did you guys solved this problem, I am having same issue, the same code is working in my another application, but not in another one, any preference or config issues ?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, using Cordova, and after adding my filesystem plugin requests in the config.xml, after already adding and building my ios platform, is this:

Remove the platform

```
cordova platform rm ios
```

Add the platform back

> cordova platform add ios

Then rebuild...  and it worked!

What I noticed in the final build of my ios platform files, the Cordova plugins for File access were not being copied over, but removing and rebuilding fixed that problem.